# using a function which was imported from another module(node.js)

Tags: node.js

that is my db.js from where i am exporting the function

```
 var mysql=require('mysql');

var config=
{
    host:'127.0.0.1',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'travel'

};
var con="";
var data=function getConnection() 
{
    con=mysql.createConnection(config);
    con.connect(function(err)
    {
        if(err!=null)
        {
            console.log('connection id: '+con.threadId);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('connection error: '+err.stack);

        }
    })
};
module.exports=data;
```

and here is my login.js file from where i am calling that exported data function

```
var express=require('express');
var db = require.main.require('./model/db');
var router=express.Router();

//routes
router.post('/',function(req,res)
{
    console.log(req.body);

});

router.get('/',function(req,res)
{
   data();
   res.render('login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the error message after running the code. can anyone please help me with that problem?

[image: error message]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need to replace `data()` by `db()`. You exported your `data` variable (which is your `getConnection` function), but imported it as `db`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the import statement as follows, because you are invoking the `data()` not `db()`. so you should change the import statement to `data` instead of `db`

```
var data = require.main.require('./model/db');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `module.exports` you're specifying the **object** that is exported, not a **name** or set of names. Since you literally just export the `data` function you want to use, the line `var db = require.main.require('./model/db');` first creates/finds that function and then assigns it to the variable `db` -- the original name doesn't matter at all.

Possible solutions to that problem (as indicated in the other answers) include replacing `data()` with `db()` or replacing `var db` with `var data`.